# How to combine two programs in one class

Tags: java

I have created two games and now I am working on menu
It should run each game after user selected each of them

Menu Must look like this:

Hello! Type 'letter' or 'number' to choose game

Heres first game:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessTheNumber {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String playAgain = "";
        
        System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 100:");
            int theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            int numberOfTries = 0;
         
            int guess = 0;
        
            while (guess != theNumber) 
                
            {
                
                guess = scan.nextInt();
                numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;
                if (guess < theNumber)
                    System.out.println(guess + " is too low. Try again.");
                else if (guess > theNumber)
                    System.out.println(guess + " is too high. Try again.");
                else {
                    System.out.println(guess + " is correct. You win!");
                    System.out.println("It only took you " + numberOfTries + " tries! Good work!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
            playAgain = scan.next();
         while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye.");
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

Heres the second

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

   public class GuessTheLetter {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);     
 String playAgain = "";
 int numberOfTries = 0;
 

do {
            

  System.out.println("Guess the Letter");


  char randomLetter = (char) (Math.random() * 26 + 65); 
  char enteredLetter = 0; 
  while(true){
     
     enteredLetter = Character.toUpperCase(scan.next().charAt(0)); 
     numberOfTries = numberOfTries + 1;
    if(enteredLetter==randomLetter)
    {
        System.out.println("Correct Guess");
        System.out.println("The letter is:"+randomLetter);
        System.out.println("It only took you " + numberOfTries + " tries! Good work!");      
        break;
    }
    else if(enteredLetter>randomLetter) 
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
        System.out.println("The letter entered is too high");
    }

    else if(enteredLetter<randomLetter) 
    {
        System.out.println("Incorrect Guess");
        System.out.println("The letter entered is too low");
    } 

   }
   
   
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again (y/n)?");
        playAgain = scan.next();
 }   while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
 System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Goodbye.");
 scan.close();
  }}
```

Must i use multiple classes, or put everything into 1, how can i combine theese two games in one?

Comment: you could do each logic of the seperate games in different funcitons. When a User type in Game1 then function1 is called when user type in Game2 function2 is caleld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each game into one function and then just call them in the main of that class. You do not need 2 classes for this. You can also add a condition that would decide which function to call.